# Повторное использование node_modules для gulp

Tags: node.js, gulp

Здравствуйте! Верстаю сайты с использованием gulp. Проблема такая: каждый раз верстая какой-нибудь новый проект приходится запускать команду npm init, которая создает папку node_modules для gulp. Вопрос: можно ли один раз где-нибудь на диске создать папку node_modules, чтобы при создании новых проектов можно было просто ссылать gulp на эту папку, чтобы не приходилось создавать node_modules по новой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js ищет модули и если они указаны без пути `require('module')`, то начинает  сразу искать в папке node_modules и будет подниматься вверх пока не найдет папку или когда он дойдет до конца вверх, он начнет искать модули уже в $PATH, поэтому вы можете свою папку добавить $PATH и node.js будет использовать плагины из нее.
Подробней о том как node.js ищет плагины можно прочитать [тут](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_all_together).

Если вы на ubuntu подобных системах, вам достаточно установить все модули в $HOME.
Если вы на windows, вы можете добавить путь через настройки.

`Мой компьютер -> Свойства системы -> Доп. параметры -> Переменные среды.`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же хочу заметить, что плагины которые ставятся глобально (с префиксом -g) не будут доступны через require(''), хоть это и называется глобально, но на самом деле префикс -g просто прокидывает бинарники (файлы в папке /.bin) некоторых модулей в PATH системы и если это обычный небольшой плагин без бинарника, то хоть он и будет добавлен в спец. директорию, вызвать его не получиться.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ, решил проблему! Пробовал через указания переменной $PATH решить проблему, но как вы и сказали: плагины глабально ставятся некорректно.

В итоге перешел по вашей ссылке, нашел инфу, что функция require() может принимать второй аргумент, который будет указывать относительный путь к модулю. Поэтому создал у себя на диске D папку со всеми нужными модулями и задал относительный путь к ней:
http://clip2net.com/s/3GhTMXG

Comment: Ваш вариант даже чище получился)

Comment: Можно еще кстати передавать аргумент NODE_PATH при запуске, тогда передавать 2 аргумент вам не понадобиться.